# Context sensitive help in XCODE IDE for Swift Framework Documentation

Tags: xcode, swift

First off, this my first post, and I apologize if this is a naive question but I have been learning SWIFT for a few weeks and trying to get some coding traction without having to constantly look at tutorials and YouTube/WWDC videos.

Consider the following code snippet.  How do I quickly find out what properties, methods, and functions are available for NSTextField from within the XCODE IDE?  I miss the old Microsoft Visual Studio CTRL+F1 context sensitive help.

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var label: NSTextField!

// Actions or Events
@IBAction func clickButton(sender:AnyObject){
   var name = textField.stringValue
   label.stringValue="Hi \(name)!"
}
```

In the XCODE IDE if I use the JUMP TO, it pops open the class which inherits from a bunch of other classes and there is no reference to .stringValue.

```
class NSTextField : NSControl, NSUserInterfaceValidations, NSAccessibilityNavigableStaticText,           NSAccessibilityStaticText, NSAccessibilityElementProtocol, NSObjectProtocol {
```

I can hop over to the Apple dev website, but still no mention of .stringValue other than it is inherited from NSControl and no example code.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextField_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextField/

Searching NSTextField in the HELP isn't helpful either.

If you could share how your work between the IDE and the framework documentation I would really appreciate your wisdom.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Ctrl+Cmd+? for context help.